# inst.setState.bind is not a function, problemas con State en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy simplemente tratando de cambiar un state por medio de handlers en react pero al ejecutar las funciones el state no cambia.

aqui tengo las funciones, el state y los objetos por donde mando los props

cabe destacar que uso webpack con babel loader

```
    export default class Game extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            pause: null
        }

    }
    PauseShow(){
        this.setState={ pause: "block" }
        console.log("pauseshow")
    }
    PauseHide(){
        this.setState={ pause: "none" }
        console.log("pausehide")
    }
    render(){

        return(
            <div className="big-box">
                <Player idc="Game" src="assets/Fly_Me_to_the_Aegis_Seven_Moon.mp3"/>
                <GameOutput/>
                <GameData pauseMethod={this.PauseShow.bind(this)}/>
                <GameInput />
                <GamePause display={this.state.pause} pauseMethod={this.PauseHide.bind(this)}/>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Aquí llamo al un handler que pasé por props

```
    export default class GameData extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="GameData">
                <button onClick={this.props.pauseMethod}>pause</button>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

**He aquí el error completo, ocurre al presionar el boton y accionar el handler**

> backend.js:8730 Uncaught TypeError: inst.setState.bind is not a function
>       at getData (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8730:49)
>       at walkNode (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8576:57)
>       at chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8579:15
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at walkNode (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8578:20)
>       at chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8579:15
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at walkNode (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8578:20)
>       at chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8579:15
>       at Array.forEach (native)

Comment: Hola, leyendo este comentario en (github)[https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/609] El error al parecer lo esta ocasionando una extensión de chrome (Lo mismo que dice tu error) en el caso del link es por el React DevTools. Así que si lo tienes lo que puedes hacer es actualizarlo. Creo que es en lo mas que te puedo ayudar por ahora.

Answer (score 1):

estas cambiando el estado de la manera incorrecta.

tu código es este:

```
this.setState={ pause: "block" }
```

cámbialo a esto:

```
this.setState=({ pause: "block" })
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es el siguiente:

tu codigo:
`this.setState={ pause: "block" }`

codigo correcto:
`this.setState({ pause: "block" })`